# Конкатенация строки с расширением одного поля в HTTP запросе при использование TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, http

Есть editField, в него пользователь вводит слова, срабатывает textwatcher, который из этих слов формирует http запрос и далее отправляет.
Проблема в том, что при вводе более одного слова, через пробел, http запрос уже не формируется, так как возникают пробелы. Решением обычно является проставлением плюса, но как это сделать если прибавляется не еще одна переменная, а расширяется имеющаяся?

Вот ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот образец урл

```
String url = String.format(context.getString(R.string.request_template),
            String.format(context.getString(R.string.query_Template), translatedTextInput, language ));
```

А вот из xml

```
<string name="request_template" formatted="false" translatable="false">https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/%s</string>
<string name="query_Template" formatted="false" translatable="false">v2?q="%s"&amp;target="%s"&amp;key=
```

PS если я некорректно составил вопрос, и хотите поставить "минус", пожалуйста оставьте комментарий к вопросу, чтобы я в дальнейшем не допускал ошибок и экономил ваше время.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286067/url-encoding-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно конвертировать строку в читабельный для URL вид.

```
String url = "https://google.ru";
String encodedUrl = null;
try {
    encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {}
```

Comment: а str это что за параметр?

Comment: Спасибо. Допер. Отличный вариант.